# Spring 4 messageSource using external file

Tags: java, spring

I'm starting using Spring 4 for my web.

Now, I'm config messageSource, it can read file internal but not for external. Please give me advice about it.

Here is my source code:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() throws Exception {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    File file = new File("/etc/messages.properties");
    if (file.exists()) {
        messageSource.setBasename("/etc/messages");
    } else {
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    }
    return messageSource;
}
```

My logic is: if file exist in /etc/messages.properties, we will use this file else we will use internal file.
But, seem it can not run now

Another part,

I want to apply this logic for environment too.
Can I set new

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
```

for environment?

Thank

Comment: Use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and prefix the file name with `file:`.

Comment: And for environment, can I change @PropertySource to external file ?

Comment: resource loading rules as explained in the spring framework reference guide apply everywhere... I suggest a read of that, in short yes just use the file: prefix.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect your thread, but did you manage to get it working?